# DataReadingMappedIfSafe Error since Swift 2.0

Tags: sprite-kit, swift2, viewcontroller

Since Swift 2.0 ] get the following error executing this line of code in my `GameViewController`:

```
var sceneData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)!
```

> ERROR: "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

Answer (score 1):

Replace with

```
NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe
```

and remove last parameter:

```
NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe)
```

Comment: I already tried that but then I get another error telling me: "call can throw, but is not marked with "try" and the error is not handled".

Answer (score 1):

the call can throw and exception, enclose your call in

```
do {
 let data = try NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options:NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe)
}catch {
     print("Error")
}
```